# how to compare two columns across many rows

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(X1 = c(37L, 36L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L, 29L, 28L, 
28L, 26L, 25L, 24L), X2 = c(40L, 44L, 49L, 41L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 
26L, 37L, 0L, 22L), M1 = c(60L, 55L, 47L, 46L, 36L, 42L, 25L, 
0L, 33L, 42L, 50L, 22L), M2 = c(19L, 0L, 32L, 44L, 27L, 31L, 
17L, 0L, 18L, 45L, 10L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I want to compare each pairs of columns

```
1 with 2
1 with 3
1 with 4
2 with 3
2 with 4
```

I want to know which rows and how many rows of column 1 has values (except 0) in comparison to other columns 
The same for the others too

for example

X1 has 12 values 
row 5,6,7, 11 has values while X2 does not 
row 8 has value while M1 does not
Row 2 and 8 has values while M2 does not

So output would be like this

```
   Total X1+  X1-  X2+  X2-  M1+  M1-  M2+  M2-
X1   12   0    0   4    0     2    0    1    0 
X2   8    0    4   0    0     1    4    2    4
M1   11   0    1   4    1     0    0    1    0  
M2   10   0    2   4    2     0    1    0    0
```

To calculate the total of each column, I can do the following

```
colSums(df != 0)
```

I tried to work with `df$X1[df$X1 %in% df$X2]` for the rest but I could not figure it out how to make such a output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I use `%>%` in `library(dplyr)` just for tidiness. I don't use other functions in it.

```
df2 <- data.frame(df != 0)
pair <- expand.grid(1:4, 1:4)
name <- names(df)

mapply(function(x, y){
  a <- sum(df2[[x]] - df2[[y]] == 1)   # TRUE - FALSE = 1
  b <- sum(df2[[x]] - df2[[y]] == -1)  # FALSE - TRUE = -1
  return(c(a, b))
}, pair[[1]], pair[[2]]) %>% t %>%
   matrix(4, 8, dimnames = list(name, c(paste0(name, "+"), c(paste0(name, "-"))))) %>%
   as.data.frame
```

---

**Output:** (I mark the two values **`X1-M1+`** and **`X1-M2+`** with *****, which means the outcomes different with yours.)

```
#    X1+ X2+  M1+  M2+ X1- X2- M1- M2-
# X1   0   4   1*   2*   0   0   0   0
# X2   0   0   1    2    4   0   4   4
# M1   0   4   0    1    1   1   0   0
# M2   0   4   0    0    2   2   1   0
```

**Description**

- **df2 :** Turn the data to booleans which mean whether the values are unequal to zero.
- **pair:** Create all possible pairs of columns.
- **a:** For the condition you expect in `X1+ X2+ M1+ M2+`
- **b:** For the condition you expect in `X1- X2- M1- M2-`

Comment: can we somehow get the row names too ? something is wrong , look at my output and yours , it is not calculated right , no?

Comment: @Learner Our outputs have two different elements, **`X1-M1+`** and **`X1-M2+`**. I check the df, and I think the values I compute are right.

Comment: @Learner I use the same rule to compute these 32 values, there is no reason that just 2 values get wrong, right?

Comment: for M1 and M2 , it is wrong. just open the data in xls and check it by hand, you can see it is not correct

Comment: Do you notice that the column order of my output is different from yours? The order of my output is `X1+ X2+  M1+  M2+ X1- X2- M1- M2-`, and yours is `X1+  X1-  X2+  X2-  M1+  M1-  M2+  M2-`. So there are only 2 values different(I mark them star symbols).

Comment: I have been trying to figure out what the problem is in your code, yes I know your output order is different. But it does not make any differences if the result is not correct. I just don't know why it does not produce the correct thing !!!! just look at X1+ and X2+ , do you see the differences ?

Comment: I checked, your `X1+` and `X2+` are equal to mine.